# Javascript : Onload with reference to class property

Tags: javascript, this, onload-event

I am trying to preload images, and at the same time get their width and height. To get the images height and width I need to use the onload method. But I cant understand how to get a reference to both the image, and the class object (from which I call from). When I find a image that is too small, I need to remove it from an array inside the class property.

Here are my code.

```
class Estate {
   this.jsonData;

   constructor() {
       this.cachePresImages();
   }

   cachePresImages() {
    let theImages = this.jsonData.images;
    for (let i=0; i < theImages.length; i++){
      let image = new Image();
      image.src = theImages[i].url;
      let that = this;
      image.onload = (that) => {
       console.log(that);
       console.log(that.jsonData.images);
       console.log(this.width);
       if ( this.naturalHeight < 10000 || this.naturalWidth < 100){
         that.jsonData.images[i].splice(i,1);
       }
      return true;
      };
    };
  } 
}
```

The above code will see that as undefined, and throw this error messages: "Cannot read property 'jsonData' of undefined at Image.image.onload"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple omit the parameter in the event handler, which overwrites your closure.

Comment: I tried that too. It will find the image by this, but not the reference to the jsonData.

Comment: Oh, wait. You where right, it worked. My bad, I looked at wrong console log error. Thanks, it works.